# How to extract the filename and path from sub directories and need to write the output into a csv file using unix shell script

Tags: sql, bash, shell, unix, csv

I need to extract the filenames as well as path in a csv file from different subdirectories in a parent directory using  unix shell script .

Requirement : I have different subfolders in a parent. Every subfolder ha one image file. Now , I need to list the filename and path of that file , And need to write the filenames and path into a csv file for all the sub directories.

Please help me out.

-Sudhir.

Comment: You can use `basename` for filename and `dirname` for path. And I think you must show some code about "what have you tried".

Comment: perhaps you could build a small example with expected output?

Comment: Hi All,  I tried this...  cd /basedata/jpegs/
ls $search_path > /testfolder/test.csv

Comment: The above will capture the file name. But I need some thing like folder path and filename in a csv for all sub directories in a parent foler. I am new to this. If anybody can give any inputs, That would be really great and helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correct, you want write filename and path to csv file.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Dir, Name" > "csvfile.csv"

files=$(find /YOURPATH -type f)

for f in $files
do

dir=$(dirname $f)
name=$(basename $f)
echo "$dir, $name" >> "csvfile.csv"

done
```

Find all files in `/YOURPATH`, write path and filename to `csvfile.csv`.

Or If you want to find just image file and if you know type, you can use like this:

```
find /YOURPATH -type f -name *.jpg
```